# How to trigger an event when there is selection inside a contentEditable div?

Tags: javascript

I want to trigger an event when the user selects some text/element in a contentEditable div. Accordingly I want to inactivate certain buttons in a Rich Text Editor.

There are some events which can be triggered based upon change of content. I only want an event when the user selects some content.

Comment: Have you attempted any code you can share?

Comment: You can probably bind a keyup event to the element and check the selection in it. You should give some code so that we can help you better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relatively simplified version could look like this, depending on your needs you might need to handle browsers like old IE's etc. that do not support `window.getSelection()`!

```js
const handleSelection = function() {
  const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
  let selection = window.getSelection().anchorNode.textContent
    .substring(
      window.getSelection().extentOffset, 
      window.getSelection().anchorOffset
    );

  if (selection.length !== 0) {
    btn.setAttribute('disabled', true);
  } else {
    btn.removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
};

['mouseup', 'keyup', 'selectionchange'].forEach((e) => {
  document.querySelector('#editable').addEventListener(e, handleSelection);
});
```

```css
#btn[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Button (disabled when something is selected)</button>
<div id="editable" contenteditable>
  <p>I'm some content that is editable!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have not tried all possibilities but I got the direction and that is good enough to accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add event listener to the element for `mouseup` event and get the selection from `window` after that:

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="editableDiv">Some content</div>
```

And the js:

```
  document.getElementById("editableDiv").addEventListener("mouseup", function() {
    var s = window.getSelection();
    if(s == "something"){
       //do your thing
    }
  }, false);
```